# Nuxt link to external url adding slash before URL

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a `nuxt-link` and if I inspect element with the Vue inspector I get something like this:

[image]

Note the `to` attribute. But if I inspect element, sure enough the `href` attribute is different:

```
<p class="more-link-block">
  <a href="/https://www.forbes.com/sites/solitairetownsend/2020/11/16/100-uk-leading-environmentalists-who-happen-to-be-women/?sh=2b11cc462451" target="_blank" class="anchor-tag small-caps">
  Trending&nbsp;→
  </a>
</p>
```

A `\` has been appended. This is not present in the JSON feed that is populating the site.

Is this a common "gotcha" with nuxt, or do I need to do something differently? Or do I need to raise an issue?

Comment: How are you generating the nuxt link?

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The NuxtLink component is used to navigate only to other pages inside your same application.

If you are redirecting your user to an external link (with a different top level domain) just simply use a regular anchor tag!

```
<a href="https://www.forbes.com/sites/solitairetownsend/2020/11/16/100-uk-leading-environmentalists-who-happen-to-be-women/?sh=2b11cc462451" target="_blank">External Link to Forbes</a>
```

Comment: Taking the above example; I'm dynamically setting the link uri text and doing <a :href="link">click me</a> and that's having the same issue in that its also generating the leading '/' as above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

### For Nuxt 2:

Use `<a>` elements for external links, instead of `<NuxtLink>`.

#### Explanation:

> The `<NuxtLink>` component should be used for all ***internal***
> links. That means for all links to the pages within your site you
> should use `<NuxtLink>`.
>
> The `<a>` tag should be used for all ***external*** links. That means
> if you have links to other websites you should use the `<a>` tag for
> those.

Source: [Nuxtjs Documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxtlink-component)

Answer (score 3):

Update in Nuxt 3, NuxtLink now supports all kinds of links, be it external or internal [Reference](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/components/nuxt-link/#examples)

> Nuxt provides  component to handle any kind of links within your application.

So your component should work fine now if you update to Nuxt 3.